# Dividir referências bibliograficas em colunas no R

Tags: r, substring, stringr

Estou com df que contém várias referências bibliográficas.
A minha intenção é dividir essas referências nas seguintes colunas: "Autor", "Titulo", "Periodico", "Dados do periodico" (volume, páginas) e "Ano"
A questão é que as referências não tem padrão.

Segue um trecho do df

```
ref<- data.frame(artigo=c("AZEVEDO, L. S. ; NASCIMENTO, E. F. ; CANDEIAS, A. L. B. . Estudo da extração de bordas de reservatório utilizando múltiplas técnicas de fusão de imagens. JOURNAL OF HYPERSPECTRAL REMOTE SENSING, v. 8, p. 95-105, 2019.",
                          "BERGER, R. ; SILVA, J. A. A. ; FERREIRA, R. L. C. ; CANDEIAS, A. L. B. ; RUBILAR, R. . Índices de vegetação para a estimativa do Índice de Área Foliar em plantios clonais de Eucalyptus saligna Smith. CIÊNCIA FLORESTAL (ONLINE), v. 29, p. 885, 2019.",
                          "AZEVEDO, L. S. ; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA . Quantitative and qualitative analysis of the IHS fusion technique applied to Landsat8 satellite images. JOURNAL OF HYPERSPECTRAL REMOTE SENSING, v. 9, p. 21-29, 2019.",
                          "SILVA, JADSON FREIRE ; MIRANDA, RODRIGO QUEIROGA ; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA . Uma nova forma de análise bibliométrica ? NAILS (Network Analysis Interface for Literature Studies): Procedimentos essenciais para pesquisadores brasileiros. Revista Brasileira de Meio Ambiente, v. 7, p. 13-28, 2019.",
                          "Oliveira, Claudianne Brainer de Souza ; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA ; TAVARES JUNIOR, J. R. . Utilização de índices físicos a partir de imagens OLI ? TIRS para o mapeamento de uso e cobertura da terra no entorno do aeroporto internacional do Recife/Guararapes ? Gilberto Freire. REVISTA BRASILEIRA DE GEOGRAFIA FÍSICA, v. 12, p. 1039-1053, 2019.",
                          "SANTOS, AMANDA PEREIRA; SILVA, EDER BATISTA DA ; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA ; COSTA, MARIA APARECIDA TENÓRIO DA . Educação critica: uma aliança entre Educação Ambiental e M-learning. EDUCAÇÃO (SANTA MARIA. ONLINE), v. 44, p. 86, 2019.",
                          "SILVA, JADSON FREIRE ; PAZ, YENÊ MEDEIROS ; LIMA-SILVA, Pedro Paulo ; PEREIRA, João Antônio dos Santos ; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA . Índices de vegetação do Sensoriamento Remoto para processamento de imagens na faixa do visível (RGB). JOURNAL OF HYPERSPECTRAL REMOTE SENSING, v. 9, p. 228-239, 2019.",
                          "ALEXANDRE, Fernando da Silva ; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA ; GOMES, Daniel Dantas Moreira . Modelagem cartográfica para a delimitação das paisagens da bacia hidrográfica do Alto Curso do Rio Mundaú - Pernambuco/Alagoas, Nordeste, Brasil. REVISTA BRASILEIRA DE GEOGRAFIA FÍSICA, v. 12, p. 2489-2502, 2019."))
```

Há alguma possibilidade de fazer essa divisão usando o stringr, por exemplo?

Consegui trabalhar com uma única referência...

```
referencia.1<- c("AZEVEDO, L. S. ; NASCIMENTO, E. F. ; CANDEIAS, A. L. B. . Estudo da extração de bordas de reservatório utilizando múltiplas técnicas de fusão de imagens. JOURNAL OF HYPERSPECTRAL REMOTE SENSING, v. 8, p. 95-105, 2019.")
str_sub(referencia.1, start = -5, end = -2 )

[1] "2019"
```

...mas não com todo o conjunto de dados

```
str_sub(ref, start = -5, end = -2)

Warning message:
  In stri_sub(string, from = start, to = end) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

Além disso, como ir extraindo esses valores em colunas à parte?
Por exemplo: colocar o "2019" que retirei em uma coluna de "ano"?

Comment: Como a parte mais complicada parece ser identificar quem são os autores em casa string, eu faria algo em partes. Em primeiro lugar, extrairia os últimos quatro dígitos de cada referência para ter o ano.  Daquilo que sobrar, eu extrairia a string a partir de `v.` para ter os dados do periódico. Do que sobrasse disso, eu extrairia o que viesse a partir do último ponto, para ter o nome do periódico. Do que sobrasse disso, eu extrairia novamente o que viesse a partir do último ponto, para ter o nome do artigo. O que sobrasse no final seriam os autores.

Comment: Logicamente, se alguma destas referências não exatamente o padrão dos exemplos dados (p. ex., algum título de artigo com `.`), este método falharia.

Comment: Marcos, obrigado. Saberia me dizer o caminho para extrair apenas os últimos 4 digitos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As referências seguem um padrão, só que não de tamanho. O formato geral é:

SOBRENOME, NOME; SOBRENOME, NOME . Titulo do artigo. TITULO DO PERIODICO, v. X, p. X-X, ANO.

Como os campos são delimitados por combinações de pontos e vírgulas, pode separá-los sequencialmente:

```
library(stringr)

# Separa os autores:
spli1 <- str_split(ref$artigo, " \\. ", simplify = TRUE)

# Separa o título dos artigos:
spli2 <- str_split_fixed(spli1[, 2], "\\. ", 2)

# Separa título, volume, páginas e ano:
spli3 <- str_split(spli2[, 2], ", ", simplify = TRUE)

referencias.df <- data.frame(
  autores = str_to_upper(gsub(" ;", ";", spli1[, 1])),
  titulo = spli2[, 1],
  periodico = str_to_title(spli3[, 1]),
  volume = sub("v. ", "", spli3[, 2]),
  pagina = sub("p. ", "", spli3[, 3]),
  ano = as.integer(sub("\\.", "", spli3[, 4]))
)


> referencias.df[1:2,]
                                                                          autores
1                            AZEVEDO, L. S.; NASCIMENTO, E. F.; CANDEIAS, A. L. B.
2 BERGER, R.; SILVA, J. A. A.; FERREIRA, R. L. C.; CANDEIAS, A. L. B.; RUBILAR, R.
                                                                                                          titulo
1                  Estudo da extração de bordas de reservatório utilizando múltiplas técnicas de fusão de imagens
2 Índices de vegetação para a estimativa do Índice de Área Foliar em plantios clonais de Eucalyptus saligna Smith
                                periodico volume pagina  ano
1 Journal Of Hyperspectral Remote Sensing      8 95-105 2019
2              Ciência Florestal (Online)     29    885 2019
```

Comment: Esse Lagosta é bom demais, nam. Outro nível

Comment: Carlos Eduardo, EXCELENTE a sua solução. Li e reli o seu código. Entendi quase tudo, só fiquei com uma dúvida: por que quando vc constrói o "referencias.df" vc utiliza "gsub" em "autores" e "sub" nos demais? Em outras palavras: qual a diferença entre "gsub" e "sub"? Quando usar um ou outro?

Comment: O *g* quer dizer "global". `sub` substitui a primeira ocorrência, `gsub` substitui todas. P.e. `sub("a", "b", "1a2a3a")` retorna "1b2a3a"; `gsub("a", "b", "1a2a3a")` retorna "1b2b3b". No seu caso, para limpar o volume e os números de página, não faz diferença, é mais hábito meu de só usar gsub quando necessário.